# How to exclude certain fields from being loaded to a POCO by Simple.Data FindAllBy?

Tags: c#, postgresql, simple.data

I have a table I want to query with Simple.Data FindAllBy() and load it into a POCO. However, there is one field in the table with binary data that I want to be excluded from this query. How can I exclude this column from being loaded by Simple.Data?

Comment: I want to select those rows, but not all the columns

Comment: Do you have any code snippet?